# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method - error in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been having an issue on a live site of mine whereas on the first load of the page in Internet Explorer the jQuery will not load and the error 'SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method' gets thrown. 
When I reload the page this error will usually disappear.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {         
        jQuery(".item-473 a").hover(function() {
           jQuery('.menu_image').removeAttr('style').attr('style', 'background-image: url(/images/volunteers_navbar.png);');
            }, function() {
                jQuery('.menu_image').removeAttr('style').attr('style', 'background-image: url(/images/adults_navbar.png);');
            });
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
<div class="menu_image" style="background-image: url(/images/adults_navbar.png);"></div>
<li class="item-472">
<a href="/activities/adults">Adults</a>
</li>
<li class="item-473">
<a href="/activities/volunteers">Volunteers</a>
</li>
<li class="item-474">
<a href="/activities/children-schools">Children & Schools</a>
</li>
<li class="item-475">
<a href="/activities/clubs-coaches">Clubs & Coaches</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a few things but I can't seem to stop this issue occurring. 
The console says the problem is on this line:

```
jQuery(".item-473 a").hover(function() {
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? 
Thanks

Comment: It is working fine 
http://jsfiddle.net/Y9btE/

Comment: Yeah it works fine on everything apart from Internet Explorer and when you first load the page up. A page refresh usually sorts it out. I'm quite confused!

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd answer this in case anybody else runs into this problem.

I found that this issue was only occurring in Internet Explorer 10 when I was implementing jQuery library plugins such as jCycle Lite and NivoSlider.

I found that wrapping my jQuery function calls with an if statement eliminated the issue that was occurring and allowed the page to load correctly.

For example:

```
            jQuery('.banner_slideshow .bannergroup_banner_slider').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'random'
            });
```

became:

```
if(jQuery('.banner_slideshow .bannergroup_banner_slider').length) {
            jQuery('.banner_slideshow .bannergroup_banner_slider').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'random'
            });
        }
```

I'm not entirely sure why this was causing a problem in IE10 but it has sorted the issue so hope it can be of help to someone else.

Thanks